# Putting images in to rows in a foreach loop

Tags: php, html, css

i have a set of image file names that are returned in this format.

Here is a var_dump() of $this->images where the filenames are  are stored

```
 array (size=9)
0 => 
object(stdClass)[8]
  public 'filename' => string '1416073696I0QHU.jpg' (length=19)
  public 'primary' => string '1' (length=1)
1 => 
object(stdClass)[9]
  public 'filename' => string '1416073696cTU23.jpg' (length=19)
  public 'primary' => string '0' (length=1)
2 => 
object(stdClass)[10]
  public 'filename' => string '1416073696uxsvq.jpg' (length=19)
  public 'primary' => string '0' (length=1)
3 => 
object(stdClass)[11]
  public 'filename' => string '1416073696uBYgo.jpg' (length=19)
  public 'primary' => string '0' (length=1)
4 => 
object(stdClass)[12]
  public 'filename' => string '1416073696vLBiH.jpg' (length=19)
  public 'primary' => string '0' (length=1)
5 => 
object(stdClass)[13]
  public 'filename' => string '1416073696rOiFe.jpg' (length=19)
  public 'primary' => string '0' (length=1)
```

i currently have the code for creating the rows needed but i am not sure how i would get the image urls inside the divs i have created, here is what the code for creating the structure looks like

```
    $images = $this->images;
    $imagesPerLine = 4;
    $arraycount = count($images);
    $ammountofrows = ceil($arraycount / $imagesPerLine);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $ammountofrows; $i++) {
        echo"<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-3'>1</div>        
    <div class='col-md-3'>2</div>        
    <div class='col-md-3'>3</div>        
    <div class='col-md-3'>4</div>        
         </div>";
    }
```

With this example we would need two rows because there are 4 images per row and we have 5 images, this code does that, but how can i then get each of image urls in to the div, so the first 'filename' out of the array dump would be in place of the 1  here

```
    <div class='col-md-3'>1</div>        

and then carry on when the next row is created
```

Here is the code that is used to generate the output since i am using an MVC system here are the model and controller that are used

Model

```
    public function GetImage() {
    $sql = "SELECT `filename`, `primary` FROM `user_img` WHERE `user_id` = :user_id";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']));
    $filepath = $query->fetchAll();
    return $filepath;
}
```

controller

```
function imageupload() {
    Auth::handleLogin();
    $profile_model = $this->loadModel('profile');
    $this->view->images = $profile_model->GetImage();
    $this->view->render('profile/imageupload');
}
```

Comment: Where that result are assigned? Where it comes from? Since the result is an object then you'll be able to do something like: `$someObj->someMethod('imageUrl');` but I need some more info to help you, can you post the code that generates the output?

Comment: if you mean the output that allows me to do
$images = $this->images; then the object comes from a PDO fetchall()

Comment: Can you post the class or method or piece of code where you're generating the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways you can attack this problem, using your method, you will need two loops, one that loops over the rows (as you have provided) and another that loops over the images.  I tend to stay away from nested loops if I can avoid them.

```
    for ($i=0; $i < $amountOfRows; $i++) {
        echo "<div class='row'>";
        for ($j=$i*4; $j < ($i*4+4); $j++) {
            if (!isset($images[$j])) {
                break;
            }
            echo "<div class='col-md-3'>{$images[$j]->filename}</div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

In the loop above, `$images` refers to the array of images.

The other option is to loop over the image array directly and use modular arithmetic to generate your gallery.  Here is one way:

```
    foreach ($images as $key=>$image) {
        if (!($key%4)) {
            echo "<div class='row'>";
        }
        echo "<div class='col-md-3'>{$image->filename}</div>";
        if (!(($key+1)%4) || (($key+1) == count($images))) {
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
```

Again in the snippet above, `$images` refers to your array containing the images.

*Note*: In the second snippet I have included the round brackets for operator precedence explicitly on purpose.

*Note2*: I encourage you to play around with the code and see if there are any improvements you can make, treat my snippets as starting points, not final solutions.

Comment: Hi Ymas, this works beautifully though i don't quite understand it, i have gone with your version of iterating over the images and not the rows, however i don't quite understand what is going on here 
       if (!(($key+1)%4) || (($key+1) == count($images))) {
            echo "</div>";
Care to explain? would be much appreciated

Comment: $key%4 is 0 whenever $key is a multiple of 4. There are two conditions that necessitate closing a row div, one is when we are at the fourth image, since array indexes start at 0, the key will be one less, concretely, in the first row, the key of the fourth image is 3, so we add 1 to it and check if the number is modulo 4 (which it is) and we close the row.  The other condition is when we get to the end of the images array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already an object in `$this->images`then you should be able to get images URL as:

```
$this->images->filename;
```

Also take into account that you're iterate over `$ammountofrows` and for get each `filename` property you should iterate trough `$this->images` or access directly to each position on the given array, for example:

```
$this->images[0]->filename; // will return 1416073696I0QHU.jpg
```